# in python3, how do i repeat a function a specific amount of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have this code:

```
for img in gst.ghostjs:
    chosenimg = pygame.image.load(img)
    newimg = pygame.transform.scale(chosenimg, (1400, 750))
    screen.blit(newimg, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(.03)
```

I have tried to use range() to do it:
for img in range(20): etc.
but then it cant find my image list

Comment: Use a different variable name for the loop.  i.e. `for x in range(20):`

Comment: `for _ in range(20): func()`.

Comment: so how would I tell it where my image list is?

Comment: `so how would I tell it where my image list is` What is "it", and what is "my image list"?

Comment: gst.ghostjs 
gst is a class and ghostjs is a list with a bunch of filenames in it

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  If you want to keep using the `for img in gst.ghostjs` loop in your code, then do that.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: it just does it infinitly. i need it to do the loop once. there are 20 images in the loop, but i need it to do that loop, then stop.

Comment: If ghostjs is a list with a bunch of filenames in it as you said, then I don't see how it can be infinite.  You must be doing something else wrong.  We can't help unless you post complete code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: oh ok thanks. ill look at the rest of my code and try to bugfix. if i still cant figure it out i guess ill post all code.